# php is not working in the server but it woks with xamp

Tags: php, sql

hello guys I hope you cam help me I have a piece of code that works fine with xamp but not in the server, any help is welcome :)

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['login_id'])) { // si no esta logeado lo regresa a login.php
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();
}

$login_id = $_SESSION['login_id'];
$login_usuario = $_SESSION['login_usuario'];
$login_perfil = $_SESSION['login_perfil'];

include 'sql.php';
//Para crear esta consulta con sentencias preparadas, primero se deben declarar las variables que se utilizarán en la consulta:
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `01proyecto`.*, `03campana`.`id_proyecto`, `proyectomm`.`id_usuario`, COUNT(03campana.id_proyecto) as total FROM `proyectomm` LEFT JOIN `01proyecto` ON `proyectomm`.`id_proyecto` = `01proyecto`.`id` LEFT JOIN `03campana` ON `03campana`.`id_proyecto` = `01proyecto`.`id` WHERE (`proyectomm`.`id_usuario` = ? ) GROUP BY 01proyecto.id");

//Luego se vincula la variable a la consulta:
$stmt->bind_param("i", $login_id);

//se ejecuta la consulta
$stmt->execute();

//se guarda el resultado
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

I have 8.1 php version in xamp and 7.2.24 in the server. is that the problem ?

thank you

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Hello @MelannieJara I hope you will find this reading useful: [PHP debugging basics](https://phpdelusions.net/basic_principles_of_web_programming#debugging)